# getter length called on null when accessing a variable of a stateful widget using its instance from another class

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

Initially, I used the page route to send the data to the next page(Question). (The data is a List Type)

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context,MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => Question(
                                            questions: this.questions)));
```

Then I received the value in the Question Stateful class using the constructor and set its value to another variable.

Question Class:

```
class Question extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<QuestionModel> questions;

    const Question({this.questions});

  @override
  _QuestionState createState() => _QuestionState();
}

class _QuestionState extends State<Question> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(widget.questions); //<----------working
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Timer(),
        SizedBox(height: 40),
        Expanded(child: QuestionBuilder())
      ],
    ),
  );}
```

when I tried to print the questions List in the Question state, it is perfectly working.

But I need that value in another class QuestionBuilder.
So, I accessed the value using an instance of the Question Class.

```
 class QuestionBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _QuestionBuilderState createState() => _QuestionBuilderState();
    }

        class _QuestionBuilderState extends State<QuestionBuilder> {
          List<QuestionModel> questions;

          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            questions = Question().questions;
            print(questions); //<---------------not working
          } 

         @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      itemCount: questions.length ?? 0,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Question  ${index + 1} / ",
                      style: Styles.questionNumberTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "7",
                      style:
                          Styles.questionNumberTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: Text(
                  questions[index].question,
                  style: Styles.questionTextStyle,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              option(option: questions[index].option_1, onTap: () {}),
              option(option: questions[index].option_2, onTap: () {}),
              option(option: questions[index].option_3, onTap: () {}),
              option(option: questions[index].option_4, onTap: () {}),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }}
```

Now When I print the questions List it is null and further when I used it in a PageView or ListView, the error shows up that the getter length was called on null.

[image]

I don't know what causes the problem.
Moreover, when tried to manually assign a dummy list value to the question list in Question class.
It works in the QuestionBuilder class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a new instance of Question class by using this code:

```
questions = Question().questions;
```

One of the simple way is to pass the value in params. For example in question class pass the data in parameter where you are calling QuestionBuilder() like this:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Timer(),
        SizedBox(height: 40),
        Expanded(child: QuestionBuilder(widget.questions),
)
      ],
    ),
  );}
```

Now define a variable to access this value passed in the param as follows:

```
 class QuestionBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
final List<QuestionModel> questions;
QuestionBuilder(this.questions);
      @override
      _QuestionBuilderState createState() => _QuestionBuilderState();
    }
```

Now in initState of QuestionBuilder access the questionList as follows:

```
 @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            questions = widget.questions;
            print(questions); //<---------------this will work now
          }
```

So now your corrected code would be, For Question class:

```
class Question extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<QuestionModel> questions;

    const Question({this.questions});

  @override
  _QuestionState createState() => _QuestionState();
}

class _QuestionState extends State<Question> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(widget.questions); 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Timer(),
        SizedBox(height: 40),
        Expanded(child: QuestionBuilder(widget.questions))
      ],
    ),
  );}
```

and QuestionBuilder would be:

```
class QuestionBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
final List<QuestionModel> questions;
QuestionBuilder(this.questions);
      @override
      _QuestionBuilderState createState() => _QuestionBuilderState();
    }

        class _QuestionBuilderState extends State<QuestionBuilder> {
          List<QuestionModel> questions;

          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            questions = widget.questions;
            print(questions); //<---------------not working
          } 

         @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      itemCount: questions.length ?? 0,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Question  ${index + 1} / ",
                      style: Styles.questionNumberTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "7",
                      style:
                          Styles.questionNumberTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: Text(
                  questions[index].question,
                  style: Styles.questionTextStyle,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              option(option: questions[index].option_1, onTap: () {}),
              option(option: questions[index].option_2, onTap: () {}),
              option(option: questions[index].option_3, onTap: () {}),
              option(option: questions[index].option_4, onTap: () {}),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response....It works like a charm.....thank you so much you saved my day man!.....btw why Question().questions doesn't work

Comment: @BalaGanesh this is happening because of two reasons. 1st you are creating a new instance of Question class to get the questions field which is wrong, other thing its compiling successfully because you have made the questions field as an optional parameter, so when you call Question().questions you are creating an new object of question class passing List<QuestionModel> questions as null